# How does PGN indicate null moves?

Tags: software, pgn, notation

How are null moves indicated in PGN which Lucas Chess will correctly interpret?

Context: I want to make PGN files of solution lines of series problems, in order to replay them in Lucas Chess. In serieshelpmates, Black plays a series of moves, with no White moves in between, until White checkmates. In other series problems, White plays a series of moves, with no Black moves in between.

Lucas Chess doesn't accept `null` or `--` as valid PGN. ([This answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/21413) mentioned `--`.)

I use Lucas Chess because it enables the user to make the app display the board diagram nice and big, with figurines in a font that is nice and clear, and even specify the square colours so that they are nice and unobtrusive. I could try another chess app instead, but I need graphics that are suitable for people whose vision is not 20/20.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that Lucas chess can not read null moves. is [Scid](http://scid.sourceforge.net/) a good enough GUI? You can create null moves there by dragging the king on the opponents king. Download [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/scid/files/Scid/Scid%20Latest/), or with a Softwaremanager on Linux.